# REGEX to format phone number in java

Tags: java, regex

given a phone number with spaces and + allowed, how would you right a regular expression to format it so that non-digits and extra spaces are removed?

I have this so far

```
String num = "        Ken's Phone is +  123   2213    123    (night time)";
System.out.println(num.replaceAll("[^\\d|+|\\s]", "").replaceAll("\\s\\s+", " ").replaceAll("\\+ ", "\\+").trim());
```

Would you simplify it so that the same result is obtained?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it as:

```
num.replaceAll("[^\\d+\\s]", "")  // [^\\d|+|\\s] => [^\\d+\\s]
   .replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ")    // \\s\\s+      => \\s{2,}
   .replaceAll("\\+\\s", "+")     // \\+          => +
   .trim()
```

Comment: This removes the space between the groups.

Comment: OP only wants **extra** spaces to be removed, not all of them and the + "with spaces and + allowed", did you run his code?

Answer (score 1):

I would put `trim()` first, or at least before you replace every multiple spaces.

Also keep in mind that `\s` means whitespaces: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r], if you only mean ' ' then use it.

A nicer way to express that you only want at least two spaces to be replaced would be

```
replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

First extract the number-with-spaces part, then compress multiple spaces to single spaces. then finally remove all spaces that follow a plus sign:

```
String numberWithSpaces = str.replaceAll("^[^\\d+]*([+\\d\\s]+)[^\\d]*$", "$1").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").replaceAll("\\+\\s*", "+");
```

I tested this code and it works.

Comment: I removed the previous comment, sorry. `replaceAll("\\s+", " ")` will replace every single space with a single space, it's more efficient to do it if there are more than one only.

Comment: It works, I agree, but is it simpler than OP's version? That was the question.